# Play sound with OpenAL

Tags: c++, boost, openal, playsound

I don't understand how I can play sound with OpenAL library. I write program for VoIP. I'm getting every 10ms sound buffer.

```
size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf),error);
```

buf is

```
boost::array <char, 441> buf;
```

And that I need to do with this buffer? I was reading examples, but didn't understand :(.
Please help me.
P.S. I use C++ on Visual Studio 2010.
After editing

```
    alGenSources(1, &alSource);
    alGenBuffers(1, &alSampleSet);
    alBufferData(alSampleSet, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), sizeof(buf.data()), 44100);
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet);
    //
    alSourcei(alSource, AL_LOOPING, alSampleSet);
    alSourcePlay(alSource);
```

Comment: Last of I tried in question.

Answer (score 0):

`buf.data()` returns a pointer, its *size* is probably either 32 or 64 bits.

The *size* of the `array` is `buf.size()` instead; and the size requested by `alBufferData` is the number of bytes in the buffer, that is the number of elements in the array `buf.size()` multiplied by the size of each element `sizeof(buf.front())` or `sizeof(char)`.
*[Note `sizeof(buf)` may probably work, at least with current Boost implementation, but I do not think that is guaranteed]*

You are specifying an `AL_FORMAT_MONO16` channel format, but you are using an odd-sized 8 bytes buffer. So that's probably an error in either the declaration of the array or the specification of the format. Based on the rest of your question, I'd assume you meant `AL_FORMAT_MONO8` there instead.

Comment: ok. I use buf.size(). But i don't have sound. At first I thought that I get wrong buffer, but if i write buffer to file, in this I have sound.

Comment: @EXTRAM: Have you been able to play **any** sound before? I.e., by trying a sample? The error(s) could be anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep the sound alive, try out this function.

```
void keepItPlay(unsigned int * source)
{
    ALint state;
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    if(state == AL_STOPPED) CleanUp(source);
}
```